# return TRUE or FALSE from a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

Here  i have a function .It accepts an array of object and a specific value.The array is iterated using a forEach method to ensure the provided value is already existed in any of the objects in the array.If found it returns FALSE ,or it should return true.But although it returns FALSE ,the rest of the code alse gets executed results in returning TRUE all the time.How i can return only FALSE/TRUE

```
   if(find_value_in_obj(all_selected,current.value)){
        all_selected.push({select_elem:current,value:current.value});
        console.log(all_selected);
    }else{

        alert("you already selected the value");   
    }

  function find_value_in_obj(arr_obj,value){

        arr_obj.forEach(function(elem,index,array){

            if(elem.value == value){
                console.log('found it ');
                return false;
            }
        });
        console.log("i am her"); // though value already exists and should returned ,it gets executed results in returning TRUE instead

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `return false;` only returns from the callback you pass to `forEach`, it doesn't have any impact on `find_value_in_obj`. You should look into using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iterates over all values.
You should be using [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

And since using `some` is just a one-liner, you don't actually need to create a helper for it, for example (from MDN):

```js
console.log([2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(elem => elem > 10));  // false
console.log([12, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(elem => elem > 10)); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` cannot be broken in middle of its iteration like a regular `for` loop. Use a regular `for` loop instead. Or, if you are using ES6 then you could achieve the same thing by using [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
function find_value_in_obj(arr_obj,value){
   return !!!arr_obj.find(itm => itm == value);
}
```

As felix suggested, you could make use of [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) also.

```
function find_value_in_obj(arr_obj,value){
   return !arr_obj.some(itm => itm == value);
}
```

Comment: But find () is an es6 feature and es6 features are not fully supported in some older versions of browsers.... :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using filter, which is more appropriate and clean.

```
   if(find_value_in_obj(all_selected,current.value)){
    all_selected.push({select_elem:current,value:current.value});
    console.log(all_selected);
}else{

    alert("you already selected the value");   
}

function find_value_in_obj(arr_obj,value){

    var resultArray = arr_obj.filter(function(elem,index,array){
        return elem.value == value;
    });

    if(resultArray.length > 0){
       return false;
    }
    console.log("i am her"); // though value already exists and should returned ,it gets executed results in returning TRUE instead

    return true;
}
```